# Cannot connect to a computer after bringing up a second NIC

Tags: networking, routing

I have a computer on campus network which I can access from outside via a ssh proxy server.

```
home --> proxy --> my computer
```

The computer has a second NIC so I brought it up to connect to some devices. To do that, I edit /etc/network/interfaces, assigned a static IP address and netmask for the second NIC, and added a route:

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

up route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1 dev eno1
```

After the NIC was up, I could no longer connect to the computer through the proxy with either ping or ssh. When I turned it down, connection came back.

I also noticed that even when the second NIC was up, I was able to connect to my computer through this route:

```
home --> proxy --> another server on campus network --> my computer
```

What could be wrong with my configuration?

```
No matter the second NIC is up or down, the computer can always access internet.
```

Comment: You seem to be adding a route to the 192.168.1.0/24 network, and the device itself ins the gateway.  That doesn't make sense.  Try without adding the route

Comment: The static route should not make a difference since it adds a route for a network you've already added. You can best discuss this with the network engineer of your campus network. What was the IP address of that other server through which you could still connect to the server? Were you trying to connect to your server using its old or new (second) IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You added a second interface to "connect to some devices". I assume these devices are on a separate IP subnet that is not accessible to the router?

IP address/netmasks for both interfaces would be helpful to diagnose the issue.

Try posting the output of `route -n` here.

I am leaning towards either:

1. The route you added is incorrect. (It appears unnecessary.), or
2. The route you added is breaking remote access, or
3. You need to specify a different metric for an interface or route.